# Socket.IO with Subdirectory

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm writing a Node.js service with SocketIO and offer multiple services via that Node.js service. Originally, I used additional path for such task, for example,

example.com/api <- routes
example.com/livechat <- SocketIO

However, the service is being moved to a virtual host with subdirectory. So instead of 'example.com' as root, I get 'example.com/nodejs/'. Problem is, socketIO still thinks it's reaching out to 'example.com', so all socket request end up in 404.

Comment: This stackoverflow answer may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25896225/how-do-i-get-socket-io-running-for-a-subdirectory

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the resource option which is defined in [Configuring-Socket.IO](https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/Configuring-Socket.IO)

This option should be set on the client and on the server

Comment: Seems that link is old, and doesn't go to the place it used to.