# How do I get socket.io running for a subdirectory

Tags: socket.io, subdirectory, socket.io-1.0

I've got a proxy running that only hits my node.js server for paths that being with `/mysubdir`
How do I get socket.io configured for this situation?

In my client code I tried:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://www.example.com/mysubdir');
```

but then I notice that the underlying socket.io (or engine.io) http requests are hitting

```
http://www.example.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1410972713498-72`
```

I want them to hit

```
http://www.example.com/mysubdir/socket.io.....
```

Is there something I have to configure on the client and the server?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

In my server I had to

```
var io = require('socket.io')(httpServer, {path: '/mysubdir/socket.io'})`
```

In my client I had to

```
<script src="http://www.example.com/mysubdir/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

and also

```
var socket = io.connect('http://www.example.com', {path: "/mysubdir/socket.io"});`
```

Comment: var io = require('socket.io')(http, {path: '/mysubdir/socket.io'}) - worked for me

Comment: Really cool, thx you for your answer.

Nota bene, it seems that the '/' in the path is mandatory. I tried 'mysubdir' didn't work out, modified with '/mysubdir' and it worked out.

Answer (score 11):

In my case I am using nginx as a reverse proxy. I was getting 404 errors when polling. This was the solution for me.

The url to the node server is https://example.com/subdir/

In the app.js I instantiated the io server with

```
var io = require('socket.io')(http, {path: '/subdir/socket.io'});
```

In the html I used

```
socket = io.connect('https://example.com/subdir/', {
    path: "/subdir"
});
```

Cheers,
Luke.

Comment: I did, now socket request url is looking fine. but I am getting No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource error

Comment: I'm getting 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'  error

Comment: has anyone found a fix for "'No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource error "

Answer (score 11):

Using nginx, this a solution without the need to change anything in the socket.io server app:

In the nginx conf:

```
location /mysubdir {
   rewrite ^/mysubdir/(.*) /socket.io/$1 break;
   proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
   proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
   proxy_http_version 1.1;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
   proxy_pass http://127.0.1.1:3000;
}
```

In the server:

```
var io = require('socket.io')(3000)
```

In the client:

```
var socket = io.connect('https://example.com/', {
    path: "/mysubdir"
})
```

Comment: I'm using nginx in kubernetes and would like to do this as well. Would you happen to know how to achieve that rewrite pattern in an `Ingress` yaml definition for kubernetes? Issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69194402/nginx-ingress-rewrite-target-with-additional-subpaths

Comment: I'm sorry but no, I did not try using nginx in kubernetes yet.

Comment: Great answer, but I would suggest small improvement. Leave the rewrite with `rewrite ^/mysubdir/(.*)$ /$1 break;` (this is my uchanged config for subfolder) and simply prefix the path on the client side: `path: (path ? path : '') + '/socket.io'` (I have made this conditional for different settings and this works even localy without subfolder)

Answer (score 3):

The answer by [@Drew-LeSueur](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25896899/535184) is correct for socket.io >= 1.0.

As I was using socket.io 0.9, I found [the old way of doing it](http://socket.io/docs/migrating-from-0-9/#configuration-differences) in the doc.

```
// in 0.9
var socket = io.connect('localhost:3000', {
  'resource': 'path/to/socket.io';
});

// in 1.0
var socket = io.connect('localhost:3000', {
  'path': '/path/to/socket.io';
});
```

Notice that a `/` appears as first character in the new `path` option.

Comment: Socket request url is looking fine. but I am getting No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource error

Comment: @DeepakDholiyan your error seems more related to a CORS issue. Is your javascript hosted on the same origine than your sockets?

Comment: Now I am getting ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Comment: @DeepakDholiyan assuming you are using socket.IO 0.9, I'm not sure you're having the issue detailed here. Maybe detailing your code and your issue in another stack overflow question will be more helpful. IMO, only telling the error you get make it very difficult for anyone to help you.

Comment: link of my question:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52411188/failed-to-load-resource-neterr-cert-authority-invalid